# DatePicker default value when saved in Yii

Tags: php, html, yii, datepicker

I'm how can I put default value on the datepicker field based on the user input? Meaning once they saved the date, it will stay on the field even when refreshed.

Here's my code for the datepicker. It successfully saved into db. But when I refresh the page, the value chosen won't be sticking at the field.

```
<div class="form-group <?php echo $model->hasErrors('accreditationdate') ? 'has-error':'' ?>">
    <?php echo $form->bsLabelEx2($model,'_dynamicData[Organization-idea-dateAccreditationStart]'); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <?php echo $form->bsDateTextField($model, '_dynamicData[Organization-idea-dateAccreditationStart]', array('nullable'=>true, 'class'=>'dateRange-start')); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you just need to set the model field to that value and it will show up automatically in the edit form not on the create form page after refrresh, and you have to provide more code if that is not the case add you form and controller action

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam , yeah basically I want the date that has been selected last time to appear on the field when I want to edit the form again to change to another date for example : I chose 2nd Feb 2018 as the date and I click save. And then when I want to edit, the date field should display 2nd Feb 2018 before I change to another date. How can I set the value?

Comment: please share your controller code for edit  action.